InfluxDB can't query data with the same query language over http
Im currently trying to get data from my influxdb from the HTTP endpoints.
Most of the queries just work fine but im having problems with one specific query which works fine in
the influxdb homeassistant interface but not on the HTTP endpoint.
This is what i use in the influx interface and it returns me the data i want to see.

SO now if i enter the same query in the http endpoint it doesnt work because it tells me the query is false. The query does work completely fine without the AND "entity_id" = 'test_tester' so the problem should be there but i cant figure it out how to get it done with the HTTP endpoint:


The issue seems to be around quotes in the string and how it's handled for the URI. Here is the curl command for the same you can try and should work:
curl -G http://localhost:8086/query \
--data-urlencode "db=home_assistant" \
--data-urlencode "q=SELECT value, entity_id as entity FROM home_assistant.autogen.W WHERE time < now() AND time > now()-10m AND \"entity_id\" = 'test_tester'"

